# Web Service returns: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to set up some simple web service with Python and Flask and SQlite3. It doesn't work.

The DB connection without web service works; the web service without DB connections works. Together they don't.

if I run this, it works:

```
import sqlite3  
conn = sqlite3.connect('scuola.db')  
sql = "SELECT matricola,cognome,nome FROM studenti"  
cur = conn.cursor()  
cur.execute(sql)  
risultato = cur.fetchall()  
conn.close()  
print(risultato)
```

(so query is correct)
and if I run this, it works

```
import flask  
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
def funzione():  
    return 'Applicazione Flask'  
app.add_url_rule('/', 'funzione', funzione)
```

but if I run this...

```
from flask import Flask  
import sqlite3  
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])  
def getStudenti():  
    conn = sqlite3.connect('scuola.db')  
    sql = "SELECT matricola,cognome,nome FROM studenti"  
    cur = conn.cursor()  
    cur.execute(sql)  
    risultato = cur.fetchall()  
    conn.close()  
    return risultato
```

It returns Internal Server Error in the browser, and 
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: studenti
on the DOS prompt.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the internal server error output - but my first guess is that you're trying to return the raw `list` object returned from `fetchall`.

When returning from a view function you need to send the results either by [returning a template](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates), or by `jsonify`ing the output to make it a proper HTTP response that the browser can receive.

You need to add

```
from flask import jsonify
```

in your imports, then when returning;

```
return jsonify(risultato)
```

If you get errors like something is `not JSON serializable` if means you're trying to send an instance of a class or similar. You'll need to make sure you're returning only plain python data structures (e.g. `list`/`dict`/`str` etc).

For the command line problem, you need to make sure you've ran a [CREATE TABLE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) command to first generate the table in the database, before you select from it. Also check you're accessing the correct `sqlite` database file with the table in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but from the look of things I don't think you've configured the flask app to support the db you created There should be some sort of app.config() that integrates the db.